# update row after Period of time using laravel

Tags: laravel

**I am developing a site that works for reservation and  i have rows for payment and status .son i need to update row for payment and status automatic after 24 hours How can  I do this**

Comment: I think you need to use task scheduling. read about it here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling

Comment: thank you bro  i will read it

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one column named 'expired_at' to your table. The value of expired_at just adding 24 hours when data saved. You can use carbon library to adding 24 hours. And check expired_at using task scheduling or cron jobs. 
If expired_at value is bigger than date now, do function.

See detail at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: Please consider adding some of the relevant info from the link in the space provided here.

Comment: https://tutsforweb.com/how-to-set-up-task-scheduling-cron-job-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

If you use cpanel you have somthing called `Cron Jobs` [image]

From `Cron Jobs` you can select php script path you want to execute and you can select slot duration